# OSX 10.11 crash after sudden hard disk removal

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

My vmware and hard disk image are on external disk and it was working fine until the external hard disk were removed by accident,
now the osx is show loading and load but shut down before show login screen.

This is link of the log file:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iB_TzHt1MNs_FMUs-gaR70F3K0YZnAWlqs_v9UruGG0/edit?usp=sharing

is there a way to solve the problem? or even a way enabling me to get data from the disk image without boot the ?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The word "backup" comes to mind...

Answer (score -2):

solved by mount the .vmdk and access its contents.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to make it clear and detailed enough that it can be used by somebody else who has a similar problem.